# JFrame buttons close to eachother

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe, jbutton

I am creating a virtual piano using JFrame, using buttons to represent keys.

```
javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane()); 
getContentPane().setLayout(layout); 
layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(
javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(
layout.createSequentialGroup().addGap(94, 94, 94).addComponent(
jButton6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 46, 
javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE).addPreferredGap(
javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
```

This is what I have come up with

[image: virtual piano]

### I want the buttons close to each other without gaps. Is there a possibility of removing the spaces between each button ?

Comment: Yes, the possibility exists. However it is hard to help you without seeing your code.

Comment: Which layout manager are you using? Please post your code.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I just designed them using the palette in NetBeans.

Comment: javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(94, 94, 94)
                .addComponent(jButton6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 46, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280281/making-jbuttons-overlap for some ideas.

Comment: the black keys would be on top right? So a higher Z-order?

Answer (score 0):

Use a layered pane, It supports the overlapping of components but you can manipulate the pane to make the components very close to each other without overlapping.

```
JLayeredPane overlap = new JLayeredPane();   
getContentPane().add(overlap);
// then you overlap.add(ITEM YOU WANT, new Integer(1));
//integers determine how you want what to overlap in an ordered fashion
```